# Injecting specific instance with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm having a few problems injecting a specific field instance with Guice.

Here's what I currently have:

```
class Driver {
   private ThreadLocal<Database> db;

   ...
}
```

I'd usually just pass the db instance in a constructor. But this class will be intercepted, using guice.

Here's the module:

```
 class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    private ThreadLocal<Database> dbToInject;

    public MyGuiceModule(ThreadLocal<Database> dbToInject) {
         this.dbToInject = dbToInject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

         // Binds the interceptor.
         bindInterceptor(....);

         bind(ThreadLocal.class).toInstance(this.dbToInject);
    }
 }
```

And here's how I'm instantiating all the stuff:

```
Injector injector = new Injector(new MyGuiceModule(db));
Driver driver = injector.getInstance(Driver.class);
```

I bet it's pretty obvious, but what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Sorry if I wasn't clear. My problem is that this is not working. The instance is not being injected. I've annotated the field with @Inject and still doesn't work.

Comment: Why not have a `Driver` constructor annotated with `@Inject`?

Comment: What's the exact problem that you're having?

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you want to improve the code? It is not clear.

Answer (score 6):

1. I think you need to use **Guice.createInjector** to create an injector instance.

   Here's how I would create an injector:

   ```
   Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule(db));
   ```
2. Another thing is you used the following code to perform binding:

   ```
   bind(ThreadLocal.class).toInstance(this.dbToInject);
   ```

   Usually, it would be something like:

   ```
   bind(MyInterface.class).toInstance(MyImplementation.class);
   ```

   Your ThreadLocal.class is not an interface class, and this.dbToInject is not your implementation class.

Here's the documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is  [Linked Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/LinkedBindings) but in the above example its [Instance Binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings)

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be better not to inject the `ThreadLocal` directly but to inject the Database into the constructor (as @Tobias suggested). And do you really want to use the same Database for all the instance of the Driver that are created (note the optional singleton in the comment)?

```java
public class GuiceExample {

  public static class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Driver.class);
    }

    @Provides
    //Uncomment this to use the same Database for each Driver
    //@Singleton
    Database getDatabase() {
      return new Database();
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testInjection() {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule());
    i.getInstance(Driver.class);
  }

  public static class Database {}

  public static class Driver {
    ThreadLocal<Database> db = new ThreadLocal<Database>();

    @Inject
    Driver(Database db) {
      this.db.set(db);
    }
  }

}
```